# Characterization of closed set using frontier points

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

I have to prove that the set $E= \{(x,y) \in R^2: x^2+y^2 = 1\}$ is closed.

Can I show the closure of the set using the result that it contains all its boundary points, given the fact that the condition in the set is expressed using the equal sign (i.e. I am working with only a circumference)? Or it is easier to use the usual definition of closed set?

Comment: Could you clarify which property you are using when you argue that the equal sign implies the closedness of $E$ ?

Comment: It certainly depends on what you are allowed to use. In my opinion, saying that $E = f^{-1}(1)$ where $f(x, y) = x^2 + y^2$ seems like the shortest way.

Comment: @StefanHamcke I was wondering if the equal sign is equivalent to state that all frontier points belong to $E$

Comment: @Tunococ Ok that is what I was thinking. But let's suppose I must use the result about frontier points. Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: It is equivalent to closedness of $E$ since, as Tunococ wrote, $E$ is the preimage of $1$ under the continuous map $(x,y)\mapsto x^2+y^2$. I thought you were using that, that's why I asked. I you want to show closedness using boundary points, just take any point $(x,y)\notin E$ and show that there is an $\epsilon$-ball around $(x,y)$ not intersecting $E$, thus proving that $(x,y)$ is not a boundary point of $E$. How would you choose $\epsilon$ depending on $\Vert(x,y)\Vert=x^2+y^2$

Comment: @StefanHamcke Ok, but is it enough to prove that a point not belonging to $E$ is not a frontier point to be able to state that all the frontier points are in $E$??

Comment: Yes, that's a logical deduction: If a point not in $E$ is not a frontier point of $E$, then all frontier points of $E$ must belong to $E$.